# Angular - 7 - How to create object from Response having many fields?

Tags: angular, angular7

How to map and use piple to create new object in Angular ? Below is the response I am getting from Service. I only want `studentId, name and Title` field.

```
{
  "studentList": [
    {
      "studentId": "e094208",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "Title": "Senior Engineering",
      "phoneNumbers": [
        {
          "number": "",
          "type": "BUSINESS",
          "public": false
        },
        {
          "number": "",
          "type": "MOBILE",
          "public": false
        }
      ],
      "emails": [
        {
          "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
          "type": "BUSINESS",
          "public": false
        },
        .......
        .......
        .......
    }
}
```

Here is the my code. How to convert it into `Student[]` with three fields?

```
student = Student[];
this.studentService.searchStudent(name).subscribe((response: any) => {
    this.studentResponse = response.studentList;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the data and map to the fields you want in the service. That is how I prefer to do it:

EDIT: Some change to the data structure as per your comment.

service:

```ts
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ....

searchStudent(name): Observable<Student[]> {
  // your function here to fetch data
  .pipe(
    map(data => {
      return data.peopleList.map(student => {
        return <Student>{ eId: student.emplNtId, name: student.name, jobTitle: student.busnTitle }
      })
    })
  )
}
```

Then in your component just assign the data to your variable:

```ts
this.studentService.searchStudent().subscribe((response: Student[]) => {
  this.studentResponse = response;
  console.log(this.studentResponse)
});
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-564u6q?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

PS: Also remember to type your data, avoid using `any` :)

Comment: What is map here ?

Comment: which one of the maps do you mean? One is rxjs `map` and second one is JS Array.prototype `map`

Comment: Can you please share import statement ?

Comment: `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: Still this is not working for me. This is my actual code

`searchPeople(searchword: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(URL+ searchword).pipe(
      map(data => {
        return {
          eId: data.emplNtId,
          name: data.name,
          jobTitle: data.busnTitle
        }
      })
    );
  }`

Comment: well those are complete different properties than you are explaining in your question. is `data` an array? Then you should use, like in my answer, array prototype `map` as well. `pipe(map(data.map(x => return {....})))` If you are still facing issues, please show the actual response you are getting, or better yet, fork my stackblitz with the correct data.

Comment: Yes data is array

Comment: then use array.prototype `map` there. Like in my answer.

Comment: Could you please update your answer ? I used exactly the same what you've used

Comment: But I **don't know** how your actual data looks like, that you are receiving. How am I supposed to update my answer if I don't know that? I'm happy to update my answer to your usecase, but you need to post a sample of your actual data.

Comment: if `data` is an array, like you say, then you should use `pipe(map(data.map(x => return {....})))` like a commented earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199632/discussion-between-paa-and-ajt82).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
var studentListParsed = JSON.parse('<YOUR JSON>');

const data: Array<Student> = studentListParsed.studentList.map(student => {
return {
    studentId: student.studentId,
    name: student.name,
    title: student.title 
    }
});
```

Comment: Why did you use var here? I need array of Student

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) something like

```
this.studentService.searchStudent(name).subscribe((response: any) => {
    this.student= response.studentList.map(x =>{
return {studentId :x.studentId ,name : x.name ,title :x.Title } as Student;
});

});
```

**Code Example**

```js
var resp={
  "studentList": [
    {
      "studentId": "e094208",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "Title": "Senior Engineering",
      "phoneNumbers": [
        {
          "number": "",
          "type": "BUSINESS",
          "public": false
        },
        {
          "number": "",
          "type": "MOBILE",
          "public": false
        }
      ],
      "emails": [
        {
          "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
          "type": "BUSINESS",
          "public": false
        }]
    }
    ]
}



var data=resp.studentList.map(x =>{
return {studentId :x.studentId ,name : x.name ,title :x.Title }
});

console.log(data)
```

Comment: @PAA can you please post here what's not working.Saying not working doesn't help to understand the actual problem

Comment: or please add the actual output you would like to get

Comment: I want to populate all in `student[]`, var will not help. student model have ID, FullName and JobTitle, there I want to map the values to create array

Comment: @PAA you can cast `{studentId :x.studentId ,name : x.name ,title :x.Title }` as `student` check out updated ans.If you still get issues please post the error here